# How to replace Union in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union

I need to concatinate results from 2 tables without using UNION.
Ex : I have 4 tables a, b, c, d. see below snips:

Table a:

[image: a]

Table b:

[image: b]

Table c:

[image: c]

Table d:

[image]

I am concatinating a and d results using UNION ALL like below:

```
            select a.id,a.seq,a.item,b.des,c.qty from a 
                left join b on a.item = b.item
                left join c on a.id = c.id and a.seq = c.seq
            UNION ALL
            select d.id,d.seq,d.item,d.des,c.qty from d
                join c on d.id = c.id and d.seq = c.seq
```

My output:

[image: output]

But I need same result without using UNION ALL.
Is it possible if so HOW?

Comment: Images of data *really* don't help us help you. Take the time to post it in a consumable format; DDL and DML statements. As for your question, why can't you use `UNION (ALL)`? That seems to be the right choice.

Comment: Without Union All you would have to insert what rows you want into a temp table and select from that

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `union all` with `full join` with a "false" condition and lots of `COALESCE()`s.

The logic looks like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(abc.id, cd.id) as id,
       COALESCE(abc.seq, cd.seq) as seq,
       COALESCE(abc.item, cd.item) as item,
       COALESCE(abc.des, cd.des) as eesc,
       COALESCE(abc.qty, cd.qty) as qty
FROM (SELECT a.id, a.seq, a.item, b.des, c.qty 
      FROM a LEFT JOIN
           b 
           ON a.item = b.item LEFT JOIN
           c
           ON a.id = c.id AND a.seq = c.seq
     ) abc FULL JOIN
     (SELECT d.id, d.seq, d.item, d.des, c.qty 
      FROM d JOIN
           c 
           ON d.id = c.id AND d.seq = c.seq
     ) dc
     ON 1 = 0;  -- never evaluates to true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `Full Outer join` instead of `Union` which has its similarities to `Union`

```
SELECT a.id,a.seq,a.item,b.des,c.qty 
FROM a left join b on a.item = b.item
left join c on a.id = c.id and a.seq = c.seq
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT d.id,d.seq,d.item,d.des,c.qty 
  FROM d join c on d.id = c.id and d.seq = c.seq
)x ON a.id = x.id
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a LEFT JOIN from table 'a' to table 'c' (on 'id' and 'seq' columns) in the upper query and INNER JOIN from table 'd' to table 'c' in the lower query.  Therefore I think you could LEFT JOIN from table 'c' to table 'd' and it would produce the correct output.

```
select a.id,a.seq,a.item,b.des,c.qty 
from a 
     left join b on a.item = b.item
     left join c on a.id = c.id and a.seq = c.seq
     left join d on c.id = d.id and c.seq = d.seq;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want you can use INSERT INTO a (tmp) table and get the same result in a table.